Elementor Search: Filtering CPT by ACF Relationship Field Meta
I’m working with Elementor Pro and ACF and need help setting up the Elementor Search Widget to show results for my custom post type project based on its ACF relationship field partner.
So if I search partner title it filters results with related projects.
What I’ve tried:

Elementor Query Settings: Attempted filtering by ACF fields but couldn't find any built in function.
Custom Query: Tried modifying search queries using PHP, but encountered issues with escaping values.

Where I got up to:

function custom_elementor_search_by_partner_title( $query ) {

        
// Check if the search is targeting a specific post type (e.g., 'project')
        if ( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'project' ) {

            
// Get the search term entered by the user
            $search_term = get_query_var( 's' );

            if ( ! empty( $search_term ) ) {
                
// Get all Partner posts that match the search term
                $partners = get_posts([
                    'post_type'   => 'partner',  
// 'partner' is the post type key
                    's'           => $search_term,  
// Searching by partner title
                    'fields'      => 'ids',  
// Return only IDs
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,  
// Get all matching partners
                ]);

                
// If matching partners are found, add them to the meta query
                if ( ! empty( $partners ) ) {
                    $partner_ids = $partners; 
// Array of matching Partner post IDs

                    
// Ensure we're passing the partner IDs correctly as an array in meta_query
                    $meta_query = array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'partner',  
// ACF relationship field name
                            'value'   => $partner_ids,  
// Array of partner IDs
                            'compare' => 'IN',  
// Compare against the partner post IDs
                        ),
                    );

                    
// Set the meta query to filter by related partners
                    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
                }
            }
        }
    }

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_elementor_search_by_partner_title' );

also tried Elementor's custom query filter:
function custom_search_query( $query ) {
// Check if the search is targeting a specific post type (e.g., 'project')
if ( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'project' ) {

    // Get the search term entered by the user
                $search_term = get_query_var( 's' );
    
                if ( ! empty( $search_term ) ) {
                    
    // Get all Partner posts that match the search term
                    $partners = get_posts([
                        'post_type'   => 'partner',  
    // 'partner' is the post type key
                        's'           => $search_term,  
    // Searching by partner title
                        'fields'      => 'ids',  
    // Return only IDs
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,  
    // Get all matching partners
                    ]);
    
                    
    // If matching partners are found, add them to the meta query
                    if ( ! empty( $partners ) ) {
                        $partner_ids = $partners; 
    // Array of matching Partner post IDs
    
                        
    // Ensure we're passing the partner IDs correctly as an array in meta_query
                        $meta_query = array(
                            array(
                                'key'     => 'partner',  
    // ACF relationship field name
                                'value'   => $partner_ids,  
    // Array of partner IDs
                                'compare' => 'IN',  
    // Compare against the partner post IDs
                            ),
                        );
    
                        
    // Set the meta query to filter by related partners
                        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
add_action('elementor/query/custom_search', 'custom_search_query');

What I'm seeking advice on:

Has anyone successfully filtered by a CPT's ACF field in Elementor?
Should I pivot to a paid plugin like JetEngine or SearchWP, or is there a better way to achieve this within Elementor?

Appreciate your responses!

The problem is the pre_get_posts. Elementor uses it's own filter for posts: https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/#using-the-custom-filter - it's elementor/query/{post_id} where post id is the custom query id you can add to the search widget under the Query tab.

Yeah I used Elementor's custom query filter for custom loop grid queries but didn't get it to work for the search widget. Edited post above with that code snippet

Right on. I'm also going to assume that your ACF relationship field is returning the Object ID and not the full Object. Trying to rule out all potential issues. Your query looks fine on first glance.

Thanks really appreciate you thinking it through. Yeah I tested both id and object outputs

Hmm...you may consider using Relevannsi Free for this. You can index the ACF/Meta fields. The Elementor Search Widget should then use the Relevannsi search index instead of the default WP built in search.

Brilliant that resolved it! Never knew of Relevannsi - who knew it was that easy. Seems like a great plugin, I'll definitely consider it for future projects. Thanks :)

Awesome! I've used Relevannsi Pro for years. It's really been indispensable. Lots of action/filter hooks available as well.
